# Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Entity's collection not tracked?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

when adding a new element to the entity's collection.

Base classes in `Domain` project:

```
public class Tour
{
        private List<Stop> _stops;
        
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public Tour(Guid id)
        {
            Id = id;
            _stops = new List<Stop>();
        }

        public IReadOnlyList<Stop> Stops { get { return _stops; } }
        
        public void AddStop(Stop newStop)
        {
            //some logic and checking
            _stops.Add(newStop);
        }
}

public class Stop
{
        public Stop(Guid id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` in the `Infrastructure` project:

```
public class TourDbContext : DbContext, ITourDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=db");
    }
    
    public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
}
```

Exception is thrown when calling `AddStopToTour()` in the `Application` project.

Interface for `DbContext`, based on: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture.

```
public interface ITourDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    ITourDbContext _context;

    public SomeClass(ITourDbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task AddStopToTour(Guid id)
    {
        var tour = await _context.Tours
                                 .Include(x => x.Stops)
                                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

        tour.AddStop(new Stop(Guid.NewGuid());
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); //Exception
    }
}
```

Shouldn't EF Core be able to track these changes automatically and add 1 new row to the Stops table? Am I missing additional configuration on entities?

Comment: Where is your DbContext ? Try to change I ReadOnlyList to IList and see that it works or not.

Comment: It's not working with IList, nor with List. What do you mean by where is dbcontext?

Comment: You have provide all necessary code to reproduce the issue. Go to how to ask question section in stackoverflow. Now if someone want to resolve your issue how do they know what you have written in TourDbContext.

Comment: Updated the question, sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: Your models simple don't match EF requirements for correct tracking.  `Stops` on the `Tour ` object will never be tracked on the Tour object as designed.

Comment: What should I specify with the fluent api? What's not covered by ef's conventions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that by generating my Id's manually, the new entity got the `Modified` state, instead of `Added` state. The fix was using the Fluent API's `.ValueGeneratedNever()` method with the `modelBuilder`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#detectchanges-honors-store-generated-key-values

Comment: Wasted days with this issue, trying different solutions. This one did the job !! But it's so unrelated to the error message.. You can never figure it out from it.